# MySQL name binding?

Tags: mysql, binding, name-binding

```
SELECT Score, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Score FROM Scores WHERE Score >= s.Score) AS tmp) AS Rank
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Can anyone tell me why s.score column unknown to the innermost subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `correlated subquery` ("tmp") is too deeply nested, in effect the details of "tmp" are not known to the outer query:

```
SELECT
      Score
    , (
            SELECT
                  COUNT(*)
            FROM ( ------------------------------
                  SELECT DISTINCT
                        Score
                  FROM Scores
                  WHERE Score >= s.Score
            ) AS tmp ----------------------------
      )
      AS rank
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY
      Score DESC
;
```

You could simply use `count(distinct score)` and just remove the unnecessary layer. However also note that it is imperative to be very precise about which columns are being used for what purpose, so make sure you **preface EVERY column reference** with a table alias or table name if no alias has been defined. No exceptions.

```
SELECT
      s.Score
    , (
            SELECT
                  COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Score)
            FROM Scores s2
            WHERE s2.Score >= s.Score
      )
      AS rank
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY
      s.Score DESC
;
```

ps: `rank()` is a function name, so I'm not really keen on using "rank" as a column name as it can get confusing.

### ----

for MS SQL Server (sorry, misread the tags, but leaving it for other readers)

I would encourage *avoid using correlated subqueries in the select clause*, it is more efficient to do this within the `from clause` and the `apply operator` available in MS SQL Server is ideal for this:

```
SELECT
      s.Score
    , ca.[rank]
FROM Scores s
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Score) AS [rank]
      FROM Scores s2
      WHERE s2.Score >= s.Score
      ) ca
ORDER BY
      s.Score DESC
;
```